# Tracking changes made in table except for one column

Tags: mysql, sql

In a table there are 2 columns named `last_active` & `date_modified`.

`last_active` is updated when page is refreshed or moved from one page to other.
`date_modified` is updated when changes made in table.

Thus as `last_active` updates, `date_modified` gets updated as `last_active` is a column in table.

Question: Is there any way to update `date_modified` for any changes made in table except `last_active`?

NOTE: For `date_modified` attribute used `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Please choose the correct database engine, MySQL **or** SQL Server.

Comment: show us your code.

Comment: mysql it is@DavidG

Comment: It is a database related problem @SqlZim